# SQL Server: REPLACE comma and combine it with similar row

Tags: sql-server

I have a **bad** table structure. I try to modify it as little as possible because the real problem is more complicated. I'm working in SQL Server 2005.

Here is my table:

**tbl_item**

```
id | item
---+------
1  | car
2  | car
3  | car, => This is what I focus
4  | jet 
5  | jet, car => This is just an example of the comma purpose
```

Query :

```
SELECT item, count(*) AS sum 
FROM tbl_item 
GROUP BY item 
ORDER BY sum DESC
```

Result:

```
item    | sum
--------+-------
car     | 2
car,    | 1
jet     | 1 
jet,car | 1
```

What I want is like this:

```
item     | sum
---------+--------
car      | 3
jet      | 1 
jet, car | 1 => actually I don't care about this, but this just for example
```

I tried :

```
SELECT REPLACE(item,',',''), count(*) AS sum 
FROM tbl_item 
GROUP BY item 
ORDER BY sum DESC
```

But the result is:

```
item     | sum
---------+------
car      | 2
car      | 1 => still in the different row
jet      | 1 
car, jet | 1
```

I can manipulate this so easy with PHP, but I wonder how to do this with pure SQL Server.

Comment: @k48 thanks for edit my question

Comment: Try to group by replace(item,',','')

Comment: @detellda work like charm man. can u post your answer. i will sign that for the correct answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
GROUP BY REPLACE(item,',','')
```

This will normalize the items, then group on them.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add it to the group by clause:

```
SELECT REPLACE(item,',',''), count(*) AS sum 
FROM tbl_item 
GROUP BY replace(item,',','')
ORDER BY sum DESC
```

Comment: this is the correct answer too, but detellda is the first one who answer. thanks for the help and edit my question